# How can I see how the MySQL database engine resolves queries internally?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use MySQL as my database engine. How can I see how the database engine resolves queries internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd help if we know what you wanted to use the tool for.

From my experience, even if such a thing were available for MySQL, it's not something I'd use for analysing/tuning performance. For general database setup I've found [mysqltuner.pl](http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl) does a very good job. While for schema / query tuning, I use [mysql_slow_log_parser](http://www.retards.org/projects/mysql/) along with some crude scripts to prioritize problem areas.

For monitoring availability, I use Nagios - which also monitors all sorts of other services.

Some discussion of the same topic on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362223/best-mysql-performance-tuning-tool)

There's several websites and books on the subject - [mysqlperfromanceblog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/?s=mysql%20tuning%20tools) is a good one

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to see is how sql queries are resolved internally, use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) (aka DESCRIBE)

> "The EXPLAIN statement can be used
>   either as a way to obtain information
>   about how MySQL executes a SELECT
>   statement or as a synonym for
>   DESCRIBE"